# Publish and subscribe from same Queue in Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to set up broadcast messaging to all nodes in the system. When a new node joins the system, it publishes a message to everyone else to announce its entry. The way I have designed is that, a exchange exists to which all nodes will bind its own queue. Whenever a new node joins the system, it will bind its queue as well to the exchange and publish a message to the exchange. All nodes will receive this msg(including itself) and all other nodes(except this message) will send a "ack" message so that the new node will get to know the available nodes in the system. But somehow I couldn't able to get this working. My broadcast messages doesn't propagate to every node in the system. A simple one node publishing and rest consuming is working. But same node publishing and consuming is somehow screwed up somewhere.

Is there any other efficient way of doing this apart from the logic mentioned above? Or is there any restriction from rabbitmq perspective to achieve the above or is my code buggy and do I have to take a closer look at it.

Comment: I do have a stop gap soltion. I have a mediator who is the only one who publishes message to the exchange. All other nodes sends a direct message to the mediator and mediator just publishes the same to the exchange. Since all nodes have subscribed to the exchange, message gets broadcasted to every node in the system. But it should be feasible to achieve w/o the mediator.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a little more detail.  What kind of exchange are you using, perhaps some code too.  What you want to do should be straight forward so I am guessing that you have a bug somewhere, either in your logic or in your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

The way you described it, your solution should work. However, without more detailed code examples (of the consume/publish logic in the "announcer" and the consume/acknowledge-publish logic in the other peers) it's difficult to debug.

A couple common problems could be tripping you up, though:

- If you're considering "did I get responses back from all the other nodes" as the authority for "did the other nodes get my announce message?", you might need to acknowledge (`basic.ack` in AMQP) the messages your announcer is receiving as it gets them. Otherwise, it's possible you're not seeing subsequent messages due to [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html), though in most client libraries you'd have to be explicitly turning that on somewhere first.

  - Make sure your other peers (the ones receiving the "announce" and sending a message back) are acknowledging the message as well, or are consuming in "no-ack" mode. Otherwise, if they get blocked (via flow, rate-limiting, or prefetch), they will probably receive announces for awhile and then stop.
  - Make sure you're using a ["fanout" type exchange](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/03/28/rabbitmq-for-windows-exchange-types/). It sounds like you want unconditional-fanout behavior, so you don't need to muck about with topic routing. If you're using a topic or direct exchange, you may have a bug in your routing logic, in which case switching to fanout will work. I suspect you're already doing this though.
  - This is likely not the issue, but: you mention that your peers (not the announcer) are "acknowledging" the announce. Make sure that they acknowledge the announce by publishing a new message back *to the announcer's queue directly* (with no exchange, just a routing key), not by sending a `basic.ack` to RabbitMQ (that doesn't notify the sender of anything), and not by publishing an announce-received to the fanout exchange.

As an aside, I don't know why you're doing declare-queue/bind/publish as opposed to publish/declare-queue/bind; is there a good reason you need an announcing node to receive its own announce message? If you're after a "self-test" behavior, I think it's probably better to just implement a periodic "can things announce successfully?" health-check somewhere instead, though that's entirely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the RPC style message, with a callback queue that you identify in the broadcast message's propeties? Like at [the rabbitmq tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html).